# Protractor promises causing headaches when retrieving elements

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angular-promise

Our web application has various html forms that each contain a list of form fields. Using Protractor, I'm looking for a way to retrieve the list of form fields: the field label, input type (textbox, select, radio, etc...), and input control (for setting the value later on). I then want to populate certain values for the fields in the form dynamically.

Here is the definition of the form field labels and the values I want to set:

```
this.fields = {
        'Listing Agent': 1,
        'Property Class': 1,
        'Property Type': 2,
        'Transaction Type': 'Sale',
        'Ownership Terms': 'Sole Ownership',
        'Listing Agreement': 'Yes',
        'Display Listing on Internet': 'Yes',
        'Display Address on Internet': 'Yes',
        'Allow Automated Valuation on Internet': 'Yes',
        'Allow Public Comment/Reviews on Internet': 'Yes'
    };
```

I then retrieve the elements that match those field names by label text:

```
this.elements = form.find.allElements(this.fields);
```

When calling that method it retrieves the correct elements, but then I'm having trouble with setting the input type for each field. Checking the input type of a field returns a promise, not the actual value, so I can't figure out how to retrieve the input type for each element and then return an array of all of the elements.

```
this.find = {
        allElements: function (fields) {
            var items = [];
            for (var key in fields) {
                var el = element(by.cssContainingText('.sheet-grid-row', key));
                this.getElementType(el).then(function (type) {
                    var item = {
                        type: type,
                        label: key,
                        isRequired: false,// TODO: el.getAttribute('class').indexOf('is-required-field') > -1
                        input: this.getElementInput(el, type)
                    };
                    items.push(item);
                });
            }
            return items;// TODO: Doesn't work, of course...
        },

        getElementType: function (el) {
            var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();

            el.element(by.css('select')).isPresent().then(function (exists) {
                if (exists)
                    deferred.fulfill(self.inputTypes.select);
                else {
                    el.element(by.css('input[type="text"]')).isPresent().then(function (exists) {
                        if (exists)
                            deferred.fulfill(self.inputTypes.textbox);
                        else {
                            el.element(by.css('input[type="radio"]')).isPresent().then(function (exists) {
                                if (exists)
                                    deferred.fulfill(self.inputTypes.textbox);
                                else
                                    deferred.fulfill(self.inputTypes.unknown);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getElementInput: function (el, type) {
            switch (type) {
                case self.inputTypes.select:
                    return new SelectWrapper(el.element(by.css('select')));
                    break;
                case self.inputTypes.textbox:
                    return el.element(by.css('input[type="text"]'));
                    break;
                case self.inputTypes.radio:
                    return el.element(by.css('input[type="radio"]'));
                    break;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
```

At this point, I wish I could just get the native DOM elements and not deal with the promises at all. Is there a way to accomplish what I'm after?

Comment: Well, you can disable the promise manager and make use of async/await.

Comment: Barney is right, use async/await and then you can just do `this.elements = await form.find.allElements(this.fields);`

Comment: Writing a test is like writing a story. By hiding the operations and logic in a generic function, you are making your tests less maintainable. It also make it harder and time expensive to determine the cause of a failure. It's just my opinion, but I think you are going the wrong way. That said you could fix your code with something like `return Promise.all(Object.keys(fields).map(keys => { var elm = ...; return elm.getAttribute('class').then(cls => ({...}))}));`

Comment: @FlorentB. I took your advice and stopped pursuing this approach, as it felt like I was fighting the framework.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do asynchronous things `element.isPresent()` inside a synchronous loop `for`. You will want your `allElements` function to look more like this:

```
this.find = {
    allElements: function (fields) {
        var self = this;
        var items = [];
        var getItems = function(inputArray, currentIndex, outputArray) {
            outputArray = outputArray || [];
            currentIndex = currentIndex || 0;
            var key = inputArray[currentIndex];
            if (key) {
                var el = element(by.cssContainingText('.sheet-grid-row', key));
                return self.getElementType(el).then(function(type) {
                    var item = {
                        type: type,
                        label: key,
                        isRequired: false,// TODO: el.getAttribute('class').indexOf('is-required-field') > -1
                        input: self.getElementInput(el, type)
                    };
                    outputArray.push(item);
                }).then(function() {
                    return getItems(inputArray, currentIndex + 1, outputArray);
                });
            } else {
                return Promise.resolve(outputArray);
            }
        };
        return getItems(Object.keys(fields));
    },

    getElementType: function (el) {
        var self = this;
        return el.element(by.css('select')).isPresent().then(function(exists) {
            if (exists) {
                return self.inputTypes.select;
            } else {
                return el.element(by.css('input[type="text"]')).isPresent().then(function(exists) {
                    if (exists) {
                        return self.inputTypes.textbox;
                    } else {
                        return el.element(by.css('input[type="radio"]')).isPresent().then(function(exists) {
                            if (exists) {
                                return self.inputTypes.radio;
                            } else {
                                return self.inputTypes.unknown;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    },

    getElementInput: function (el, type) {
        switch (type) {
            case self.inputTypes.select:
                return new SelectWrapper(el.element(by.css('select')));
                break;
            case self.inputTypes.textbox:
                return el.element(by.css('input[type="text"]'));
                break;
            case self.inputTypes.radio:
                return el.element(by.css('input[type="radio"]'));
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```

Keep in mind that the output of `find.allElements` is now a promise, as it should be, so its usage will be something like:

```
this.find.allElements(this.fields).then(function(items) {
    console.log('this is an array of my ' + items.length + ' items');
});
```